# Is there a way to combine a product or sum of two cosines into one?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Is there a way to combine a product or sum of two cosines into one? More specifically:

$$
A \cos \alpha \cos \beta = B \cos \gamma
$$

or:

$$
A \cos \alpha + B \cos \beta = C \cos \gamma
$$

I've been doing some research and I found "linear combination of cosine and sine with equal periods". This "would" work for the latter case if one of the cosines was transformed into a sine, but still (even after the transformation):

$$
\alpha \neq \beta
$$

and:

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \neq \beta
$$

Thus, it will not work. I also know about the product-to-sum and sum-to-product identities, but that does not really help here. Is there a way of doing it? What if:

$$
\alpha \propto \beta
$$

where the ratio is a rational number, but not necessarily an integer? Any suggestions and guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Send something to show where do you start from and where you want to arrive

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
 \cos \alpha \cos \beta =  \cos \gamma
$$
where
$$
\gamma=\arccos(\cos \alpha \cos \beta)
$$
The same for sum.

Comment: This is circular. Not exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you though.

Comment: Your answer doesn't account for $A,B,C$.